# How to add validators for @Html.TextBox() without model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a part of my view

```
@model bhavin.Models.Employee

@using (Html.BeginForm("BuynowForm", "Home"))
{
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Billing Address</label>
   @Html.TextBox("bill_address", null, new { @class = "form-control valid" })
</div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</p>
 }
```

I want to add required validation to it. The billing_address textbox is not a part of the models.employee. 
I am using mvc5 So how to add the validator?

Comment: Use a view model that includes all the properties your need.

Comment: try by adding data-* attributes as how here - `@Html.TextBox("bill_address", null, new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Billing Address is required" })`. Do not forget to add unobtrusive and validate JS files.

Comment: @ramiramilu It worked..Thank you. But where I can print the "Billing Address is required" message? It is not coming. I am new to mvc.

Comment: use `@Html.ValidationSummary()` Can I post this as an answer?

Comment: Yes. you should actually. pleas include validationsummary() details also. It worked perfectly for me. Thank you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `data-val` and `data-val-required` attribute for `Html.TextBox()` as shown below.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>    

@using (Html.BeginForm("",""))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.TextBox("bill_address", null, new { @class = "form-control valid", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "Billing Address is required" })
    <input type="submit" value="Click" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**NOTE**

1. `@Html.ValidationSummary()` is used for printing validation message.
2. Do not forget to include - `validate` and `unobtrusive` JavaScript files.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the support . If you can share some links to know other properties like @data_val_required , (can be string minimum length) , it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's what you're looking for, but look a this :

In your `BuynowForm` method, add a `string` parameter called `bill_address`.

On the form submit, you'll get the input value in this `string`, and you'll be able to make your validations.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually i was looking for something else and marked one reply as the answer to the question. Thanks for the reply